# Flask PyMongo HTML show Read Data

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm with my teams are currently working on some project face recognition presence system for COVID-19 anticipation, so people don't have to touch unnecessary things in the factory.

Right now, i am trying to show the data absence (for HRD / absence administrator access only) from my team's mongoDB atlas. My HTML is loaded but it seems it's only load blank data.

this is my app.route /database on `app.py`

```
@app.route("/database", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def database():
    if not session.get('email'):
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        dataCollection = mongo.db.Presence_Data_Table.find()
        data = []
        for i in dataCollection:
            data.append()

    return render_template('database.html')
```

and this is my `database.html`

The relevant code:

```
<body>
    <div class="head-title">
       <h1>Admin Sign up</h1> 
    </div>
    <table>
    {% for i in dataCollection %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>{{ i['Nama'] }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{ i['Tanggal'] }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{ i['Waktu'] }}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>{{ i['Activity'] }}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what's wrong with it?
I'm sorry, i'm still newbie in flask development

Here what it's show up on my browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Rx1.jpg

And here's what's inside dataCollection
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8icTS.jpg

Comment: Hey welcome to SO , could you please update what's in `dataCollection` , as you are appending nothing to `data` as well you are not sending to template too :)

Comment: Which ever python variables you need to display in template, you need to pass it.

Comment: hey @Codenewbie, thanks for the warm welcome. I did update what's inside the ```dataCollection```. However, if you think my provided data isn't sufficient, just let me know, and i will ask my leader to give more. 
Also, what do you mean by "template"?

Comment: @ngShravil.py, i'm really sorry, but i don't really understand what do you mean "pass it"

Comment: @NikolausAdven I really recommend you to go through https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/  ...... hope you get some idea :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code above you are using the variable dataCollection , however as mentioned in the comments by ngShravil.py . You do not pass the variable from your back end web server to your browser.

You need to modify the following lines:

```
return render_template('database.html')
```

to this:

```
return render_template('database.html',data=data)
```

---

and then in your .html file do this :

```
{% for i in data%}
```

Comment: i already did 
```return render_template('database.html',dataCollection=dataCollection)```
before, but it still unsolved. Anyway, thanks for the help. I'm gonna try add the 2nd fix

Comment: @NikolausAdven My bad take a look at my modified answer